# How to access request body model fields on DRF server side?

Tags: java, android, python, json, django-rest-framework

On the android client side, I make a request to a server endpoint with a body of `ContactRequest`:

```
public class ContactRequest {

    @SerializedName("senderId")
    @Expose
    private int senderId;

    @SerializedName("receiverId")
    @Expose
    private int receiverId;

    public ContactRequest(int senderId, int receiverId) {
        this.senderId = senderId;
        this.receiverId = receiverId;
    }
}
```

Using retrofit I pass this object as the request body:

```
@POST("friendship/create-friend-request/")
Call<Void> sendRequest(@Body ContactRequest contactRequest);
```

On the server side, I then map this endpoint to the `CreateFriendRequestView`:

```
class CreateFriendRequestView(views.APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sender = User.objects.get(pk=request.senderId)
        receiver = User.objects.get(pk=request.receiverId)
        Friend.objects.add_friend(sender, receiver)
        return Response({'status': 'Request sent'}, status=201)
```

However when the request is made to this endpoint and when the view is called, an internal server error, status code 500 occurs.

> AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'senderId'

How can I make reference to the fields, `senderId` and `receiverId` on the django rest framework client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the request data is in `data` field of request object.

checkout http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data

You have to use:

```
sender = User.objects.get(pk=request.data.get('senderId'))
```

request.data is a python dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, alternatively it can be accessed using: request.data['senderId']

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just that the `get` method allows you to give a default value in case the given key is not present in the dict. for eg: `request.data.get('senderId', 1)`